# Determinant of a matrix of size n

Tags: matrices, determinant

I received a matrix for which I need to calculate its determinant.
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \cdot & \cdot & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
1 & 1 & \cdot & \cdot & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & 1 & 0 \\
     \end{pmatrix} \in \operatorname{Mat}_n (\mathbb{R})
$$

My calculation procedure is as follows:
$$\begin{align}
A \cong & \prod^{n-1}_{i=0} E_{i,n,-1} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 1 & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \cdot & \cdot & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
1 & 1 & \cdot & \cdot & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & 1 & 0 \\
     \end{pmatrix}
 = \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & \cdot & \cdot & 0 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \cdot & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
0 & 0 & \cdot & \cdot & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & 1 & 0 \\
     \end{pmatrix}
 = A_1 \\
\\
\\
A_1 \cong & \prod^{n-1}_{i=0} E_{n,i,1} \cdot A_1
 = \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & \cdot & \cdot & 0 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & \cdot & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
\cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot \\
0 & 0 & \cdot & \cdot & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & \cdot & \cdot & \cdot & 0 & n - 1 \\
     \end{pmatrix}
 = A_2
\end{align}$$

Explanation of the above:

- $E$ is an elementary matrix.
  The sign $E_{i,j,\lambda}$ means "Add to row number #i the row number #j multiplied by $\lambda$".
- $n$ is the matrix size.

The matrix $A_2$ is equivalent ("row-equivalent") to $A$, using only the "Row addition" operation , therefore their determinants are equal.

We can see that matrix $A_2$ is an upper triangular matrix, therefore its determinant is equal to the multiplication of the items in the main diagonal: $(-1)^{n-1} \cdot (n-1)$.

Please confirm my solution.
Also, do you see any easier way for solving this?

Comment: Some care is needed here: two of the (usually) three elementary row operations **do change** the determinant, namely: swaping rows (multiplication of determinant by $\;-1\;$) , and multiplying a row by a non-zero scalar (multiplies the determinant by that scalar.)

Comment: @Timbuc I know, but I didn't use those operations, therefore the value of the determinant didn't change :)

Comment: I meant your comment 4 lines before the last one.

Comment: @Timbuc Oh, indeed, gotcha!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to diagonalize it. Let 
$J = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & \cdots  & 1 \\
1 & ...  &1 &  \\
1 & \cdots & 1 \\
 \end{pmatrix} $

Then $A=J-Id$

$rgo(J)=1$ so $0$  is eigenvalue with multiplicity $n-1$

$J\cdot(1,...,1)^t=(n,...,n)^t$ so $n$ is eigenvalue too.

Then $J \simeq
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \cdots  &0& 0 \\
0 & ... & 0 &0 &  \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & n \\
 \end{pmatrix} $
so $ A = J-Id \simeq
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & \cdots  &0& 0 \\
0 & ... & -1 &0 &  \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & n-1 \\
 \end{pmatrix} $

so $\det(A)=(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)$